# Multiple Redux states in a single component - Typescript, React, Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router

During authentication I return some internal ids that need to be carried into other components throughout the users life cycle. These values are kept in the `authentication` state, and all other relevant component logic is kept in the `resources` state.

When I am running with multiple states in the component, it appears the authentication state overwrites the resources state in someway making the values I'm getting `undefined` despite the React state definitely having the values (Confirmed using the React Dev Tool).

Here is the relevant code from my component:

The props type:

```
type ResourceProps =
    ResourceState.ResourceState
    & AuthState.AuthState
    & typeof ResourceState.actionCreators
    & RouteComponentProps<{ }>;
```

Redux connect:

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.resources && state.authentication,
    ResourceState.actionCreators 
)(ResourceDisplay) as typeof ResourceDisplay;
```

Example of how I'm using the different states. Please see my comments in the code:

```
    //customerInfo comes from authentication state.
    if (this.props.customerInfo.subscriptions.length == 0) {
        console.log('empty subs list');
    }
    else {
        this.props.customerInfo.subscriptions.forEach(function (subscription) {
            // retrieveResources is an action being called from resources. This action populates the resources state.
            this.props.retrieveResources(subscription);
        });

        // This is the resources state that is definitely populated but returning `undefined` in the code.
        console.log(this.props.resources);
    }
```

Am I just fundamentally misunderstanding how connect actually connects props to the Redux state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you expecting `connect()` to do here?

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.resources && state.authentication,
    ResourceState.actionCreators 
)(ResourceDisplay) as typeof ResourceDisplay;
```

Because at the moment, what you're saying is to only return `state.authentication` if `state.resources` is "truthy" (which it probably is). In other words, `state.resources` won't be passed to your component.

I'm guessing you actually want to combine properties from both? If that is the case you need to do something like:

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => { ...state.resources, ...state.authentication },
    ResourceState.actionCreators 
)(ResourceDisplay) as typeof ResourceDisplay;
```

Or use `Object.assign()` or something else (not entirely sure what props format you expect from your code).

Comment: This is definitely what I am trying to achieve, I was very tired at the time and feel really stupid for making such a mistake. I'm having problems with the Typescript compiler claiming that the class provides no match, but that's somewhat answered my question and progressed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! This was causing me issues too!