# Multiple Redux states in a single component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I want to merge multiple states into a component (I'm suing TypeScript).
I notice that this issue was discussed 2 years ago - [Multiple Redux states in a single component - Typescript, React, Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48659484/multiple-redux-states-in-a-single-component-typescript-react-redux).
I tried the proposed solution but it didn't work for me. 
any other suggestion?

```
type CompetitorProps =
CompetitorsStore.CompetitorsState // ... state we've requested from the Redux 
store
& StationsStore.StationsState
& typeof CompetitorsStore.actionCreators // ... plus action creators we've 
requested
& RouteComponentProps<any>; // ... plus incoming routing parameters


const Competitors = (props: CompetitorProps) => {

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("In Competitors. useEffect1");
    ensureDataFetched()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("In Competitors. useEffect2");
    ensureDataFetched()
}, [props.selectedStationID])

const ensureDataFetched = () => {
    props.requestCompetitors(props.selectedStationID);
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <h1 id="tabelLabel">Competitors</h1>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table aria-label="simple table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">ID</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Name</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {props.competitorsArray.map(competitor => (
                        <TableRow key={competitor.nCompetitorId}>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row"> 
                              {competitor.stCompetitorName}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right"> 
                              {competitor.nCompetitorId}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right"> 
                              {competitor.stCompetitorName}</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    </React.Fragment>
   );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => ({
competitors: state.competitors,
stations: state.stations
});

export default connect(
(state: ApplicationState) => { ...state.competitors, ...state.stations }, 
CompetitorsStore.actionCreators 
)(withRouter(Competitors as any));

//export default connect(
//    mapStateToProps, 
//    CompetitorsStore.actionCreators 
//)(withRouter(Competitors as any));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*it didn't work for me*"? What exactly is your issue?

Comment: I tried { ...state.competitors, ...state.stations } and i received: "(TS) No overload expects 3 arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either 3 or Infinity arguments." What is the correct syntax for it?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: In order to help you, we need some more information. A few tips: post the relevant code in the question. Include information about your unsuccessful attempts. Links to other questions or off-site resources are fine, but include the important parts in your own question. More details on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I attached above

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having? Is there an error? What is the expected outcome vs what you actually get?

Comment: I want to merge the competitor state and the station state into competitor component. I tried the suggested solution { ...state.competitors, ...state.stations } and i received: "(TS) No overload expects 3 arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either 3 or Infinity arguments." I also tried the mapstatetoprops and the useeffect(The first one) was not processed.

Comment: @user342319 where is that error occurring? Can you post it so we can see which piece of code it's complaining about?

Comment: I recieved it during compilation. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

OK, firstly keep your `mapStateToProps` function so you can focus your 'merge' there

```
connect(mapStateToProps, etc)
```

based on what you have said you want to swap

```
competitors: state.competitors,
stations: state.stations
```

for one property (what you are calling 'merge')

Not sure why you want to do this, but basically you want to create a single object on a single prop which contains both competitors and stations

I have concluded this from this code: `{ ...state.competitors, ...state.stations }`

So change your mapping to one property:

```
competitorsAndStationsMerged: { ...state.competitors, ...state.stations }
```

or you could do

```
competitorsAndStationsMerged: { competitors: state.competitors, stations: state.stations }
```

Is this what you are trying to do?